# Detecting a Change of Value on a Folder Content Type Custom Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-column

We are using Sharepoint online,
On here we created a group of custom columns for our documents, that allow the users to tag the document and using a app we develop search the documents they want later using these tags.

Now we wanted to tag folders also so we created a Content Type Based on the folders and we are able to search and retrieve folders with the tags also.

Now the next step it that when a user tags a folder, the tag should be propagated to all items, and other folders bellow it.

I have been researching but i don't see to be able to find any way to this.

Any one has any ideas on how i could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

While you can set up folders with metadata that is automatically inherited by new documents created inside the folder, existing documents will not automatically inherit changes to the metadata of the folder. You would need to adjust these manually, or consider writing a Power Automate flow to automate that.

Comment: any link to how i could do this? I am using sharepoint online.

Comment: Have you used Power Automate before? It has its own learning curve. You can start a flow when an item is modified in a library. They you would need to find a way to filter to the documents you want to change and then use a loop to change their metadata. It will not be easy, but it should be doable. The details, however, are not something I can put in one answer here, because this is not a script writing service.